# How to populate one column on the basis of other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table like this:

```
|-------|----------|------------|-----------|------------|
| M_ID  | YEAR     | NEW_M_ID   |STATUS_CODE|GROUP_NUMBER|
|-------|----------|------------|-----------|------------|
|111    |2010      |111-2010    |    0      |            |
|111    |2011      |111-2011    |    0      |            |
|111    |2013      |111-2013    |    1      |            |
|111    |2014      |123-2014    |    0      |            |
|123    |2009      |123-2009    |    0      |            |
|123    |2010      |123-2010    |    3      |            |
|123    |2014      |123-2014    |    0      |            |
|-------------------------------------------|------------|
```

I want to populate the value in group_number column on the basis of other column.
and desired output should look like this:

```
|-------|----------|------------|-----------|------------|
| M_ID  | YEAR     | NEW_M_ID   |STATUS_CODE|GROUP_NUMBER|
|-------|----------|------------|-----------|------------|
|111    |2010      |111-2010    |    0      |      1     |
|111    |2011      |111-2011    |    0      |      1     |
|111    |2013      |111-2013    |    1      |      1     |
|111    |2014      |123-2014    |    0      |      2     |
|111    |2015      |123-2015    |    0      |      2     |  
|123    |2010      |123-2010    |    3      |      1     |
|123    |2014      |123-2014    |    0      |      2     |
|-------------------------------------------|------------|
```

the code I used is like this:

```
declare
    group_num number:=1;
    old_acct CHAR(15):=' ' ;
    short_acct_number CHAR (10):= ' ';
begin
    for i in (
        select ACCT_NUMBER, status from xxx.transaction 
        order by acct_number
    )
    loop
        short_acct_number := SUBSTR(i.ACCT_NUMBER, 1, LENGTH(i.ACCT_NUMBER)-5);

        if short_acct_number <> old_acct then
            group_num := 1;
        end if;

        if i.status <> 0 then
            update xxx.transaction set group_number = group_num
            where  acct_number <= i.acct_number
            and    group_number is null;

            group_num := group_num + 1;
        end if;

        old_acct := short_acct_number;
    end loop;
end;
```

The problem with my code is it does not populate group_number as 1 in 6th row, which is mistake.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you please describe the logic behind how you calculate the `GROUP_NUMBER` values?

Comment: I don't understand - do you expect us to guess the requirement? Do you think it is self-evident? (IT ISN'T!) How do you think we can help you if we don't know what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Currently, you are setting group_num to 1 for every iteration in the `DECLARE` statement. For row 6, the second IF is true, so it's adding 1 to the current group_num value of 1, for a result of 2. Something in your logic is wrong if that's the result set you expect. However, there's not enough information to determine what it is.

Comment: Is there a problem with the rows having year columns of `2009` and `2015`?

Comment: The code refers to columns `acct_number` and `status` that aren't mentioned in the sample data. Is 'a table' `xxx.transaction`? Is `status` the same thing as `status_code`? Is `xxx` relevant?

Comment: I don't know if its related, but `char` variables are just asking for trouble. Should a 15-byte blank-padded value ever match a 10-byte blank-padded value? Turns out it does, but sticking to standard types makes code easier to predict.

Answer (score 1):

Send below query output.

```
select ACCT_NUMBER, status from xxx.transaction 
order by acct_number
```

Comment: Huh? "Below" is a query, not a query output. "Send"? Where? To whom? What does this have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: @mathguy, I think that he wants the OP to post result of that query. Why? Because PL/SQL code OP posted references ACCT_NUMBER column which doesn't exist in sample table data. STATUS is probably STATUS_CODE, but - what is ACCT_NUMBER? So, without the OP explaining what he wants (with words, as you've already come to conclusion that the desired result isn't self-evident), referencing unknown columns certainly doesn't help. Though, Indrakumara should have posted it as a comment (does lack of reputation prevent him from doing so? I guess; that's why he posted an *answer* instead).

Comment: I would agree with Littlefoot :-) I too felt that the comment was unnecessarily offensive. Something like this  would have been more appropriate.  "Kindly post your answer as a comment or wait till you have sufficient reputation or op provides details". It's my opinion that's all, not targeting anyone.

Comment: @Littlefoot, You are very true. it should add as a comment. what I am tried to do is get the better picture of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is how your code calculation is working
Declaration:

group_num = 1
old_acct = ‘ ‘

Loop

Iteration 1 and 2 status code = 0 does not enter the loop

Sets old_acct = short_acct_number

For iteration 3 status code = 1 enters the loop

Sets group_num= group_num + 1 = 1+1 = 2

For iteration 4 and 5 status code = 0 does not enter the loop

For iteration 6 enters the status code and updates group_number = group_num

Which was set to value 2 in iteration 3 as explained above.

This is why you don’t get Group_Number of 1 in your sixth column.
If 1 is exactly what the answer should be you need to fix the group_num calculation but at this point you don’t give us the logic behind setting group_number.
Also on the cursor

```
Select Acct_Number , status from xxx.transaction
```

If your xxx.transaction table only includes the columns you have mentioned above there is no way for us to understand the logic , please share more information on that too.